# How to aggregate the field values of objects in a list into a row in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I have a table with id and a list of JSON-like objects containing names. I need to convert this list of objects into a single string with the names separated by commas.

Original table

```
1 [{'name':'John', age: 23}, {'name':'Mary', age: 50}]
2 [{'name':'Joseph'}]
3 []
4 [{'name':'Alexander', age:12}, {'name':'Martha', age:42}, {'name':'Eugene'}]
```

Expected result

```
1 John, Mary
2 Joseph
3 NULL (or empty string)
4 Alexander, Martha, Eugene
```

I've experimented with a LATERAL JOIN together with a FLATTEN function but that doesn't seem fit as it generates more rows. Should I use that and then group by with listagg? It feels like there's an easier way of doing it.

Here's a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ZEEvhzCiEVBhmyPiPxzGo/7) with both tables.

Comment: youe db-fiddle is for MySQL, not a snowflake.

Comment: I couldn't find any Snowflake playground. I'm adding the Snowflake DDL to db-fiddle now

Comment: Your db-fiddle  is for MySQL. Please show us your effort in a subject you provided. You did wrote that you can just access JSON data and do a query. What is the question? If you get errors or complications in your code, show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used dataset as below -

```
select * from tab_names_json;

+---------------------------+
| NAMES                     |
|---------------------------|
| {                         |
|   "tab2": [               |
|     {                     |
|       "name": "Joseph"    |
|     }                     |
|   ],                      |
|   "tab3": [],             |
|   "tab4": [               |
|     {                     |
|       "age": 12,          |
|       "name": "Alexander" |
|     },                    |
|     {                     |
|       "age": 42,          |
|       "name": "Martha"    |
|     },                    |
|     {                     |
|       "name": "Eugene"    |
|     }                     |
|   ],                      |
|   "tabl": [               |
|     {                     |
|       "age": 23,          |
|       "name": "John"      |
|     },                    |
|     {                     |
|       "age": 50,          |
|       "name": "Mary"      |
|     }                     |
|   ]                       |
| }                         |
+---------------------------+
```

Note: The file I loaded actually had 'tab*' ordered from tab1 to tab4; however,
order is not preserved in JSON.

Query to fetch.

```
select distinct listagg(ifnull(tab1.name,'null'),',') 
within group(order by tab1.name) 
over (partition by tab1.seq) as agg 
from
(select f1.seq as seq,f1.value:name as name from TAB_NAMES_JSON t, 
lateral flatten(input=>t.names) as f, 
lateral flatten (input => f.value,mode=>'ARRAY',outer=>TRUE) f1) tab1;

+-------------------------+
| AGG                     |
|-------------------------|
| Joseph                  |
| null                    |
| Alexander,Eugene,Martha |
| John,Mary               |
+-------------------------+
```